# Transformation from $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1) a_{k+1} x^{k+1}$ to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k) a_{k} x^{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm looking over an answer key and struggling to understand how one sum is simplified to another.

The original sum is:

> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1) a_{k+1} x^{k+1}$

And the simplified form is:

> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k) a_{k} x^{k}$

Could someone explain how this is possible? I think it has something to do with the first term of the series being 0 but I'm not sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: the $k=0$ term of the second series is $0$, and otherwise the series are identical, so they are equal. It may be helpful to think of it as first making a substitution $\ell=k+1$ and rewriting the first series as

$$\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\ell a_\ell x^\ell$$

and then adding tacking on an $\ell=0$ term to get

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\ell a_\ell x^\ell\;;$$

since the $\ell=0$ term is $0$, the two series have the same partial sums. Now just rename the index variable from $\ell$ back to $k$.